# AngularJS local queue for deffering updates to view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch

I have a view that displays a list of entries. I have a service that pushes in new entries to my view. But if user is adding a new entry or editing an entry, I want to defer pushing new updates, so user do not see the view jump around.

The way I am thinking of it currently is having a local queue. Add a $watch to listen to see if user is editing an entry. Any new updates coming from the service, I will push that in the queue. When the $watch says that user is not editing, push the updates.

This all seems good, but might get extensively complex. I am new to angular and wanted to see if there is something angular provides or there is a simpler solution I could utilize here.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: just started reading about $q https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. wondering if I could utilize that.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an alright plan. Another option would be to set a parameter, such as `item.isNew = true` on the new items marking them as new. Use `ng-if="!item.isNew"` (or `ng-show="!item.isNew"`) to hide the new elements. When the user is done editing you can then set all the `item.isNew`s to `false`.